# Checking whether a string starting with 0x is a hex in python

Tags: python

I have strings of the form `"0x3f"`, `"0x2d"`.

How to check if it is a valid hexadecimal number and how to convert it to decimal value directly?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`int`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) and catch `ValueError`:

```
>>> try:
...     value = int('0x3f', 16)
... except ValueError:
...     print('Invalid hex string.')
...
>>> value
63
>>> try:
...     value = int('0xzz', 16)
... except ValueError:
...     print('Invalid hex string.')
...
Invalid hex string.
```